# useEffect + React Router not updating correctly with useLocation

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I am trying to program a simple component that moves the user to new Routes based on scrolling the mouse wheel, up until recently it has been working fine (scrolling up goes to the route listed above and vice versa) however there is a page where I do not want scrolling to change the route.

when I added a simple if check to my handleNavigation function to check if the user was on the route where I want to disable scrolling to different routes, I quickly ran into the problem that is not working, my logic is correct because when I manually go to the route (/work/portfolio) and try scrolling, the scrolling is disabled, however when following a link to it naturally, the scrolling feature is not disabled, I suspect that the useEffect event listener is not updating correctly, but I have location in the dependency array so it should update, why am I still able to scroll?

[image: Edit fast-sky-kbm006]

check the codesandbox above for the replicated issue: scroll to the very bottom, each scroll of the mouse wheel should route to a new page and then the final route '/work/' should appear, click on the link and notice that you are still able to scroll, when you should not be able to

Comment: I think you work is not saved in codesandbox,

Comment: seems working, did you fixed your code? (edit original question or delete it pls)

Answer (score 1):

I have seen your Sandbox. Add some function definition in `Work.js` component and then render it'll work fine.

```
import React from "react";

function Work() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> Hii From Work</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Work;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I saved to codesandbox correctly or not but there already is a function definition in work.js, the problem is in the nested route i am still able to scroll when that shouldnt be the case